# Noise in polynomial systems.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system, perturbation-theory

Consider equations of the form

\begin{equation}
n_1 x^i + n_2 y^i = s_i
\end{equation}

where $n_1, n_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ are known coefficients and
$s_i > 0$ is a real constant.

Fix two indices $i<k$ and consider the following polynomial system

\begin{align*}
n_1 x^i + n_2 y^i = s_i\\
n_1 x^k + n_2 y^k = s_k
\end{align*}
with solutions
$(x_1, y_1), \ldots,(x_{ki}, y_{ki}) \in \mathbb{C}^2$. I know that
for this system there exists at least one solution
$(x*, y*) \in (0,1)^2$.

Now consider the following perturbed system
\begin{align*}
n_1 x^i + n_2 y^i = \widetilde{s}_i\\
n_1 x^k + n_2 y^k = \widetilde{s}_k
\end{align*}
where $|\widetilde{s}_i - s_i | < \epsilon_i,\ |\widetilde{s}_k - \widetilde{s}_k| < \epsilon_k$. Let $(\widetilde{x}_1, \widetilde{y}_1),
\ldots, (\widetilde{x}_{ki}, \widetilde{y}_{ki}) \in \mathbb{C^2}$ be the solutions of the perturbed system.

**Question**

> I would like to measure the "impact" of the perturbations of the coefficients $s_i, s_k$ on the solutions of the system. References on similar topics are welcome.

Comment: Have you considered a first-order Taylor series expansion about $(x^*,y^*)$?

Comment: @Rahul You mean consider the solution $(x^*, y^*)$ as a function $G(x,y, s_i, s_k) =0$ and then take the partial derivatives with respect to $s_i, s_k$ ?

Comment: No, I mean what N74 has just posted in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all it is better to write the solution to the perturbed system this way

\begin{align*}
n_1 \widetilde{x} ^i + n_2 \widetilde{y} ^i = \widetilde{s}_i\\
n_1 \widetilde{x}^k + n_2 \widetilde{y} ^k = \widetilde{s}_k
\end{align*}

Where $\widetilde{x}=x(1+\delta_x)$ and $ \widetilde{y}=y(1+\delta_y)$.

When the deltas are little we can rewrite the system as :

\begin{align*}
n_1 x^i (1+i\delta_x) + n_2 y^i (1+i\delta_y) = {s}_i+\epsilon_i\\
n_1 x^k  (1+k\delta_x)+ n_2 y^k  (1+k\delta_y)= {s}_k+\epsilon_k
\end{align*}

Simplifying out the known factors

\begin{align*}
n_1 x^i i\delta_x+ n_2 y^i i\delta_y= \epsilon_i\\
n_1 x^k  k\delta_x+ n_2 y^k  k\delta_y= \epsilon_k
\end{align*}

This is a first order linear system for $(\delta_x,\delta_y)$. You can solve it and study the range of variation of the deltas as $(x, y)$ vary in $(0,1)^2$.

Comment: Thanks, is there any text on such methods ?

Comment: You can start here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Experimental_uncertainty_analysis and follow the references.